# Regarding memory usage of Java Application

Tags: java, tomcat, memory, jvm

I have a question regarding memory usage of java web applications..

In Task manager,  Tomcat service seems to occupy **8,677,544,000** Bytes of memory

In jvisualvm, memory usage of java application deployed under that tomcat is as follows

```
Heap: 
Used: 2,304,233,184 B
Size: 8,589,934,592 B
Max: 10,737,418,240 B

Permgen:
Used:  80,272,056 B
Size: 536,870,912 B
Max:  536,870,912 B
```

Memory Parameters in Tomcat's Service.bat file:

```
-Xms8192m;-Xmx10240m;-XX:PermSize=512m;-XX:MaxPermSize=512m
```

Now, my question is no matter what I set MaxHeapFreeRatio the free space is not shrinking even though the used space is shrinking at times.

Can anyone, kindly tell me why is this behaving like this.. Is there a way to shrink the free space so that other processes runnning on the system can utilize it?

I am using latest versions of JDK 1.7 & Tomcat 7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the parameter `-Xms8192m` you're telling Tomcat (well, the JVM) to allocate at least 8 GiB of heap space on startup.

The JVisualVM stats support that, but also tell you that around 2 GiB is being used by the application.

Reduce the start-up value to a lower value (start at 2 GiB). Note that if the application needs more heap space, you've told it you can use up to 10 GiB `-Xmx10240m` so it may be worth trimming this value down too (maybe to 4 GiB).

Obviously, if you start to get OOME's, you'll need to increase the values until the application has enough to run happily (assuming no memory leaks etc.).

Also, note that the process size will always be larger than the heap size as it also includes the perm gen space (`-XX:MaxPermSize=512m`) and internal memory / libraries for the JVM itself.

---

**Basic examples:**

```
-Xms512m;-Xmx1536m;-XX:PermSize=64m;-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
```

The minimum values here are 512 MiB heap, 64 MiB perm gen, so the minimum OS process size would be around 600 - 650 MiB.

As the application allocates more space up to the max values (1.5 GiB heap, 256 MiB perm gen) I'd expect the process size to reach about 2 GiB.

Now if we use your values:

```
-Xms8192m;-Xmx10240m;-XX:PermSize=512m;-XX:MaxPermSize=512m
```

The minimum values here are 8 GiB heap, 512 MiB perm gen, so the minimum OS process size would be around 8.6 GiB - pretty much exactly what you're seeing.

Using the max values, the process size would reach nearly 11 GiB.

Comment: Thanks Mikaveli.. Your response provides very good information on memory. I will definitely reduce size of minimum memory and try.. But my question is how to make OS release unused memory efficiently (without any issues) so that other processes can use it..

Comment: Once it's allocated the heap space (up to the `-Xmx`) it won't usually release the memory back to the OS. Instead, just try not to allocate more than your app will use - in your case, you're allocating 6 - 8 GiB more than necessary, which could be used by other processes.

Comment: I went through some articles yesterday.. You are right..It won't release memory back to OS. Thanks for your help..

Comment: You're welcome. Feel free to 'accept' my answer (by clicking the tick under the vote count) if you've found it useful.